# Schedule command are not run on server

Tags: laravel-5, cron

I add a cron job in my project But the cron job is not working properly on ubuntu server. I search for the solution but cannot find.

Here is the code of `Console/Kernel.php`.
Where I set my shedule commands. And also tell that i am not use any time like (daily()) then after how much time that command run?

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
   /**
       * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
   *
   * @var array
   */
   protected $commands = [
     //
   ];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Api\ScheduledNotificationController@moodCapacityReached')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Api\ScheduledNotificationController@upcomingWeekEvent');
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Api\ScheduledNotificationController@upcomingDayEvent');
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Api\ScheduledNotificationController@upcomingHourEvent');
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Api\CompanyCheckinController@beforedaycheckin')->daily();
    $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Api\MoodOfTheDayController@beforeDayMoods')->daily();
}

/**
 * Register the commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function commands()
{
    $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
```

}

And Here is the Controller code that run after the command call:

`CompanyCheckinController.php` file:

```
public function beforedaycheckin()
{
    $companycheckin = CompanyCheckin::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->toDateTimeString())->get();
    CompanyCheckin::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->toDateTimeString())->delete();
    // return response()->json(['Checkin' => $companycheckin], 200);

}
```

I Run this command one server to run schedule command as a root user.

`sudo crontab -e`

But the method is not call and `companyCheckin` can not deleted after 24 hour. I do not find any solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `scheduler` has known issues. Not sure if it has gotten better in latest version release but after having lots of issues with it in Laravel 5.3, I have decided to do not rely on it.

My advice is that you are far better off, creating your commands in Laravel and then setting CRON on the server directly via cPanel or terminal instead of doing it via the scheduler.

If you have cPanel on your server, it's fairly simple to add a cron which runs your command script at a given time interval. For instance if you want to run a script every minute you simply add this:

```
*   *   *   *   *   php {full_path_to_your_project_root}/artisan {command:signature} >> {full_path_to_your_project_root}/storage/logs/{name_of_log_file}.log
```

and voila. This way your cron run logs will also be recorded in `{name_of_log_file}.log` just for debugging purposes.

You can verify various time settings for cron on: https://crontab.guru/